# How to print boolean return value

Tags: python

The following two functions produce similar results

```
def is_between(x, y ,z):
    return x <= y <= z
is_between(1, 2, 3)

def is_between(x, y, z):
    if x <= y <= z:
        print(True)
        return True
    else:
        print(False)
        return False
is_between(1, 2, 3)
```

The first function returns a boolean value more efficiently than the second function. The second function, on the other hand, uses conditionals to describe how it would return true and when it would return false, providing us with the opportunity to print each of those possibilities, were they to happen.

Is it possible to print or otherwise use the boolean value returned by the first function? I tried print(is_between) but that was incorrect.

**Solution:**

*This works*

```
def is_between(x, y ,z):
    return x <= y <= z
print(is_between(1,2,3))
```

*This does not*

```
def is_between(x, y ,z):
    return x <= y <= z
is_between(1,2,3)
print(is_between)
```

Comment: Just `print(is_between)`? Are you familiar with calling functions?

Comment: I passed it values at the end, closing off the function. Jack has shown that it works if you pass the values in the print statement itself.

Comment: And did you try the `bool()` function anywhere? Also note that the second function doesn't return `True` or `False`; it's always `None`.

Comment: You say the first function returns a boolean value more efficiently than the first. The second function does not return a value at all.

Comment: Yeah I know that the second function does not return a boolean. If you read into the context of the question which was more or less made explicit, I'm interested in using or printing the value returned.

Comment: Is your question about how to convert to boolean values? Or how to print? Or how to make a function call? Or what gets returned and when? This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print(is_between(1, 2, 3))`.

You *can* `print(is_between)`, but you'll get something like `<function is_between at 0x7fde2aebee18>`. That's because you haven't *called* the function. You need to pass in arguments to the function to get a result.

You can either print the result directly, as above, or use the result -- assign it to a variable (e.g. `returned_value = is_between(1,2,3)`), use it in a conditional (`if is_between(1,2,3):`...), etc.

Comment: I was providing arguments at the end of the functions, and trying to print immediately after that. You method of including arguments in the print statement works. I don't know why you're getting downvoted. I will mark as correct answer after the time limit elapses and I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Best Solution to print the return value of a function

def is_between(x, y ,z):
    return x <= y <= z
print is_between(1,2,3)

Here is a link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to print a boolean returned from a function is to use a ',' instead of concatenating with '+' sign. 
Example:

```
    def bird_available(name_of_bird):
       bird_types = 'crow robin parrot seagle sandpiper hawk pigeon'
       Case = name_of_bird.lower() in bird_types
    return Case

    name_of_bird = input('enter a type of bird to search: ')   
    birds = bird_available(name_of_bird)
    print('the bird '+name_of_bird+'is ' ,birds)
```

you can also print the `bird_available(name_of_bird)` using the ',' instead of making it a variable.

Answer (score -1):

To use simply do :

```
if is_between(1, 2, 3):
    # Do somthing
```

To print simply:

```
print(is_between(1, 2, 3))
```

Problem in your code is that you are trying to print function not its return value.